# Mobile Email Tracking

Tags: email, tracking

I'm an email marketer, and have a question. I'm looking for a way to see which app mobile readers are using to open my emails in.

Currently, I embed a pixel from Returnpath, so I know that the majority of my mobile readers are using iOS devices, but I'm wondering how many of them are using the native apple app or are using mailbox or the gmail app. This would help me develop adaptive/responsive mobile friendly emails or just reduce the template size to be mobile friendly.

I can track through GA if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: survey in mail asking them. and explaining that you will use this to improve layout. but really wish the mails looked okay across clients

Answer (score 0):

Normally with tracking you get email client tracking, device or OS tracking is secondary if at all. I know on both Campaign Monitor and Litmus it is all about the email client.

If something says iOS, and it is in a list with gmail, outlook, yahoo etc, it is the native app by mac, not gmail. Not sure if mailbox would fall under 'other' as a client.